# iOS GoogleCast SDK V2.7.1 Returns null when getting modelName and deviceVersion

Tags: ios, chromecast, google-cast

I am using version `2.7.1` of the `google-cast-sdk` and I'm trying to get the device modelName and deviceVersion. I am planning on upgrading to the latest GoogleCast version btw, I'm just stuck on this version for now.

I am getting them like so:

```
NSLog(@"deviceInfo: %@, %@", deviceManager.device.modelName, deviceManager.device.deviceVersion);
```

Both of them return `null`. I have tried this on the latest version of the Googlecast SDK and it appears to be working.

Has anyone successfully got the modelName/ deviceVersion from the SDK v2.7.1?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with iOS GoogleCast SDK but did you try using `NSString * modelName` and `NSString * deviceVersion` under [`GCKDevice Class`](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/ios/interface_g_c_k_device)?

Comment: @Mr.Rebot, thanks for the comment. Isn't that what I'm pretty much doing in my above code? `deviceManager.device` is the `GCKDevice` object.

Comment: I'm using version 3.5.0 of the Cast SDK and it returns back the following data for both 1st and 2nd generation of Chromecast devices: `manufacturer: nil`
`modelName: Chromecast`
`deviceVersion: 05`